# How do I show an error message to a user in different part of page?

Tags: php, html

I've got a "validation script" on the first line of my page. It's right before `<!DOCTYPE html>`. The script validates the input and if there's an error, it should **display an error somewhere upon the footer** in the html part. There are more php script all over the html.

So how do I display an error in **an other part** than in the start of page (the part with php script)?

Little example how it looks like:

```
<?php
if($form->isValid())
{
   // redirect
}
else
{
   // a function to display error upon the footer ? 
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="example">
    <?php // some other script
      foreach(...){ ?>
     <a href=""><?php echo $a[0]; ?></a>
   <?php } ?>
   </div>

   <!-- Here it should display the error -->
   <footer>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm quite a beginner so I would very appreciate your help!

Comment: use `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy — Not a different page. A different part of the same page.

Comment: It is invalid to have any non-whitespace data in an HTML document before a DOCTYPE declaration, and it causes Quirks Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable at the point you determine an error should be shown.

Test the value of that variable at the point where you want to display the error.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. I was thinking only about some complex solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($form->isValid())
{
   // redirect
}
else
{
   // a function to display error upon the footer ? 
    $error = true;
    $errorMessage = 'fill the blanks';
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="example">
    <?php // some other script
      foreach(...){ ?>
     <a href=""><?php echo $a[0]; ?></a>
   <?php } ?>
   </div>

   <!-- Here it should display the error -->
   <?php
   if($error){
       echo "<p>{$errorMessage}</p>";
   }
   ?>
   <footer>
   </footer>
</body>
</html>
```